# Listview Upper Bounds and Lower Bounds do not interact when the user reaches the limits

Tags: android, listview, scrollview

My listview is in a scrollable view, when I reach the Upper bound limit or the lower bound limit the listview doesn't show the blue circle from the bounds. How can I make the layout shows it?
After adding the overScrollMode=Always still it is not working, This Layout is added in the ScrollingActivity sample provided by Android.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:overScrollMode="always"
    android:fillViewport="true>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:id="@+id/snackBarLocation">

        </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="55dp"/>

        <android.support.v4.widget.Space
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <android.support.v4.widget.Space
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Text"
            />

        <android.support.v4.widget.Space
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="10dp" />

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: You may want to show us some code of what you tried :)

Comment: I added the layout of the activity

Answer (score 0):

This is called "over-scroll".

You can change the over-scroll mode via XML:

```
android:overScrollMode="always"
```

Or via Java:

```
setOverScrollMode(OVER_SCROLL_ALWAYS);
```

See https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html#setOverScrollMode(int) for more information.

Comment: I did what you mentioned still no result.